# OST file becoming corrupted repeatedly in Outlook 2019

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

We have a mailbox that's approximately 55 GB in size, which seems to work fine on one PC with Office 365 after increasing max OST file size. Another PC on the other hand is running Office 2019 and the OST file gets corrupted on a regular basis (about every four hours or so). This happens when interacting with emails (e. g. forwarding, deleting, etc.). SCANPST.EXE is able to fix the file but after a random amount of time, it bricks again.

We've tried everything from recreating the profile, inbox or reinstalling Office and nothing has helped yet. Any idea what's happening here and what we can do to get the Outlook installation back to a working status?

Thanks.

Comment: Try reducing the size of if. Stellar Tools.

Comment: If it was the size, why would it work on another PC though :(

Comment: I use Office 365 not Outlook 2019 so I am not sure if Outlook 2019 is the issue?

Comment: @John - According to my research, all the most recent versions of Office (2021, 2019, 2017, 2016, 2013) all default to 50 GB `.OST` files. If the author has modified the registry key responsible for the maximum size, and is NOT getting the dialog that indicates the file is to large, then the file corruption likely has less to do with the file size rather the storage drive.  My guess the drive has problems. Office 365 and Office 2019 are essentially the same version, or were at one point, and to my knowledge Outlook other than interface changes hasn't seen huge improvements.

Comment: Yep, I modified the registry and am not getting any warnings, also the PC with O365 is having no problem at all. I checked the drive's SMART, it reports that everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, the overall size of .pst and .ost files has a preconfigured limit of 50 GB. And i notice that your mailbox is 55GB, which exceeds the maximum size. Actually, problems during use are the expected behavior and the performance in Outlook365 is unexpected.

In order for you to continue to use Outlook normally, please try to reduce your mailbox size in two ways:

[Export or backup email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91)

[Archive items manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6)

Comment: You linked to an article about the limitations of a .PST file, not a .OST file, there is a huge difference.

Comment: I added the registry configuration to not get any warnings about the 50 GB size and the other PC with O365 has no problems at all, would the size really lead to file corruption?

Comment: When the WarnFileSize or the WarnLargeFileSize limit is reached, e-mail messages cannot be sent (provided that sent e-mail messages are stored in the Sent Items folder), and items cannot be copied or moved within the file. If the file is an archive .pst file that is used for AutoArchive, the AutoArchive operation will fail. However, e-mail messages can be deleted or archived from a .pst or from an .ost file that is currently being used as the default delivery location.

Comment: (References: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-configure-the-size-limit-for-both-pst-and-ost-files-in-outlook-2f13f558-d40e-9c2a-e3b6-02806fa535f4#:~:text=If%20.ost%20files,default%20delivery%20location.)

Comment: Yea but that's just stating that it will stop working when it reaches the configured size in the registry, which is why I increased these limits (which is also mentioned in the article) and what is working fine on a different PC.

Comment: If so, i'm afraid that you need to do the same behavior in the computer with Outlook 2019 as in computer with Outlook 365. (change the registry)